# What subspace of $\operatorname{SU}(4)$ group keeps an element of the $\mathfrak{su}(2)$ subalgebra within $\mathfrak{su}(2)$ upon adjoint action?

Tags: rt.representation-theory, linear-algebra, lie-groups, lie-algebras

Consider the Lie group $G_4=\operatorname{SU}(4)$ with (15) generators $T^a$. A basis for the latter is
$$\{\sigma^j \times 1_2, \quad \quad \sigma^i \times \sigma^j, \quad \quad 1_2 \times \sigma^j\},$$
with $i,j=1,2,3$. The three $1_2\times\sigma^j$ form a $S_2=\mathfrak{su}(2)$ subalgebra. Consider the adjoint action of an arbitrary group element $U\in G_4$ on the algebra element $1_2\times \sigma^3$ and demand that the resulting Lie algebra element remain in $\mathfrak{su}(2)$, that is
$$U (1_2 \times \sigma^3)U^\dagger \overset{!}{\in} S_2 = \text{span}\left\{{1_2\times \sigma^j}\right\}$$
My question is, for what $U$ is the above is satisfied?

**Some thoughts:** It is possible to write an arbitrary $G_4$ element as
$$U= e^{i\alpha^k (1_2 \times \sigma^k)} e^{i\beta^l (\sigma^l \times 1_2)}e^{i(\sigma^i \times \sigma^j)\gamma^{ij}}$$
the $\alpha^k$ and the $\beta^l$ correspond to ‘rotations’ within and orthogonal to the $S_2$ subgroup respectively and so both will keep and element of $S_2$ within $S_2$. So the more to-the-point question is for what space of $\gamma_{ij}$ is
$$e^{i(\sigma^i \times \sigma^j)\gamma^{ij}}(1_2 \times \sigma^3)e^{-i(\sigma^i \times \sigma^j)\gamma^{ij}} \in S_2.$$
For example, if I only turn on $\gamma^{i3}$ then the exponentials commute with $1_2\times \sigma^3$ so the above is satisfied trivially...

Comment: You say "a basis for the latter", but so far you've only mentioned one thing (the Lie group $G_4 = \operatorname{SU}(4)$), and I don't know what a basis of a group is.  You then mention "the latter three", but that follows a mention of only three objects.  You then refer to a subspace of $G_4$—are you somehow identifying groups and Lie algebras?  What does $\overset!\in$ mean?

Comment: a meant a basis for the $T^a$, which are the generators, i.e. Lie Algebra elements. It's not the clearest apologies. By latter 3 I meant $1_2 \times \sigma^j$, j=1,2,3. I've tidied it up a bit. I mean there's a subspace of $G_4$ (the group) which takes, through adjoint action, the element $1_2 \times \sigma^3$ to the subalgebra spanned by $1_2 \times \sigma^j$, j=1,2,3. By $\overset{!}{\in}$ I mean imposing that it be an element of.

Comment: I don't follow your notation, but I think this subspace is the normalizer $S ( U(2) \times U(2))$ of $\mathfrak {su}_2$, which possibly involves setting your $\gamma$ to $0$. Because these elements normalize $\mathfrak{su}_2$, they clearly keep your element in $\mathfrak{su}_2$, so we need to check the converse. An element of $g\in U(4)$ keeping your element $x$ in $\mathfrak{su}_2$ must send $x$ to one of the same trace, so there is $h\in S(U(2) \times U(2))$ conjugating $x$ to $g(x)$.

Comment: Then $h^{-1} g$ is in the centralizer of $x$, which is $S ( U(2) \times U(1) \times U(1)) \subset S( U(2) \times U(2))$ as long as $x$ has two distinct nonzero eigenvalues, and in general is contained in $S ( U(2) \times U(2))$ as long as $x$ does not have a zero eigenvalue. With a zero eigenvalue, this subset will be larger.

Comment: @WillSawin I don't quite follow. What does the S(..) notation mean? In any case there are definitely non-zero values of $\gamma^{ij}$ that work. I've edited my question to stress this. Any combination ${\gamma^{i3}\neq 0, \gamma^{i2}=0,\gamma^{i1}=0}$, for $i=1,2,3$ for example trivially works.

Comment: $S$ of a group just means the elements of that group with determinant $1$.

Comment: Are you saying that the centraliser of an element of a subgroup is a subset of the normaliser of that subgroup? This does not seem obvious to me, though it might be a standard theorem..

Comment: I don't think the set I am interested in is contained in the normalizer. Counterexample: $g=e^{t(i\sigma^2 \times \sigma^3)}$ commutes with $1\times\sigma^3$ but when conjugating $1\times\sigma^2$ is takes it out of $\mathfrak{su}(2)$ subalgebra.